# Mysql table format lost when passed into a pipe

Tags: mysql

```
[root@tokyo-b ~]# mysql -e 'select NOW();'
+---------------------+
| NOW()               |
+---------------------+
| 2019-09-05 21:35:49 |
+---------------------+
```

VS

```
[root@tokyo-b ~]# mysql -e 'select NOW();' | cat
NOW()
2019-09-05 21:34:51
```

Table format lost.. anyone can explain this?

Comment: MySQL probably checks whether stdout is the console.

Comment: Specify `--table` command line option additionally. And maybe `--batch` option too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mysql command probably detects it being run as part of a pipe and it removes the formatting on purpose.
Many Unix/Linux command line utilities do this to make it easier for a subsequent commands in the pipe to extract the data without having to worry about the additional formatting characters.